Getting 'KeyError' that i can't contain "." in directory
I'm trying to merge LoRA to base model.
I got
KeyError: 'module name can't contain ".", got: C:/Users/tjs/.cache/huggingface/FinGPT'
It's just worked yesterday, but not now.
Since i'm just a newbie, and only know basics, i have no idea how to solve this problem.
import torch
import os
import logging
import argparse
from tqdm import tqdm
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
from peft import PeftModel


base_model_name_or_path = 'NousResearch/Llama-2-13b-hf'
peft_model_path = 'FinGPT/fingpt-sentiment_llama2-13b_lora'
output_dir = ("C:/Users/tjs/.cache/huggingface/FinGPT")
device = "auto"
push_to_hub = False

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


try:
    if device == 'auto':
        device_arg = {'device_map': 'auto'}
    else:
        device_arg = {'device_map': {"": device}}

    logger.info(f"Loading base model: {base_model_name_or_path}")
    with tqdm(total=1, desc="Loading base model") as pbar:
        base_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
            base_model_name_or_path,
            return_dict=True,
            torch_dtype=torch.float16,
            **device_arg
        )
        pbar.update(1)  

    logger.info(f"Loading Peft: {peft_model_path}")
    with tqdm(total=1, desc="Loading Peft model") as pbar:
        model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(base_model, peft_model_path, output_dir)
        pbar.update(1)

    logger.info("Running merge_and_unload")
    with tqdm(total=1, desc="Merge and Unload") as pbar:
        model = model.merge_and_unload()
        pbar.update(1)

    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(base_model_name_or_path)

    model.save_pretrained(f"{output_dir}")
    tokenizer.save_pretrained(f"{output_dir}")
    logger.info(f"Model saved to {output_dir}")

except Exception as e:
    logger.exception("An error occurred:")
    raise

I found it could be the problem of version, which didn't worked for me.
And i also tried to remove ".", but changing the directory seemed to be impossible.

what do you mean changingthe directory seems to be impossible? after removing the . are you sure the full path C:/Users/tjs/cache/huggingface/FinGPT exists? if not you should probably create those subdirectories, otherwise post your error

@Kenzo Staelens
Firstly, i got some issue with offload directory.
I could fix it by adding offload_folder = "offload/" when loading peft model.
But soon i got NotImplementedError: Cannot copy out of meta tensor; no data!

does this question help in any way?

@Kenzo Staelens [UserWarning('do_sample is set to False. However, temperature is set to 0.9 -- this flag is only used in sample-based generation modes. You should set do_sample=True or unset temperature.'), UserWarning('do_sample is set to False. However, top_p is set to 0.6 -- this flag is only used in sample-based generation modes. You should set do_sample=True or unset top_p.')]
I added do_sample=True, but it's not working anyway
